# /category switch is not working correctly when using in ANT xml for mstest.exe

Tags: xml, ant, mstest, categories

I am invoking mstest.exe from an XML as:

```
<exec executable="${mstest}">
    <arg value ="/category:${test}"/>
    <arg value ="/TestContainer:${Destination}\bin\Debug\UnitTestApp.dll"/> 
    <arg value="/resultsfile:${Destination}\testResults.trx"/>
</exec>
```

Where

```
<property name ="mstest" location="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe"/>
<property name ="test" value="MyTest"/>
```

When the Ant executes the command I see correct values are passed:

```
   [exec] Current OS is Windows 7
   [exec] Executing 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe' with arguments:
   [exec] '/category:MyTest'
   [exec] '/TestContainer:C:\VS2012\myApp\UnitTestApp\bin\Debug\UnitTestApp.dll'
   [exec] '/resultsfile:C:\VS2012\testResults.trx'
   [exec] 
   [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
   [exec] not part of the command.
Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe' with arguments:
'/category:MyTest'
'/TestContainer:C:\VS2012\myApp\UnitTestApp\bin\Debug\UnitTestApp.dll'
'/resultsfile:C:\VS2012\testResults.trx'

The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.
```

But when the test is executed I see the message:

```
[exec] Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 11.0.50727.1
[exec] Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[exec]     
[exec] Loading C:\VS2012\myApp\UnitTestApp\bin\Debug\UnitTestApp.dll...
[exec] Starting execution...
[exec] No tests to execute.
```

If I do not use the /category switch . It works OK and all tests defined in the code are executed but I do not want that. I want to run a specific test.

Why Ant is having a problem using /category switch.

From CMD ( windows 7 ) if i pass the same arguments to mstest.exe on the same machine where the Ant is getting executed, all is ok. /category:MyTest is getting picked up as expected. Please help.

Comment: In cmd.exe, from what directory do you run mstest.exe? You may need to set the `dir` attribute of `<exec>`.

Comment: should it matter which directory I run the mstest.exe from? I gave the full path to the mstest.exe in the property. And also Its running from the  C:\VS2012 directory.

Comment: Instead of using mstest.exe I invoked a batch file to run mstest command with arguments mentioned above. Still it can not pick up the switch /category and complains about no test to run. So I am starting to believe its mstest problem. Execute the batch file from command line there is no issue. Execute the batch file from ANT, You have the problem no test to execute.

Comment: and specifying "dir" property for exec does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

problem does not seem to be ANT . I used the following and it works OK.

```
<target name="pb">
<exec executable="mstest">
<arg value="/TestContainer:C:\VS2012\myApp\UnitTestApp\bin\Debug\UnitTestApp.dll"/>
<arg value ="/resultsfile:C:\VS2012\testResults3.trx"/>
<arg value ="/category:MyTest"/>
</exec>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wondering how I got around the issue ? 
I created an XML to execute the commands like this below and then invoking it with msbuild.exe. :

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Build">
  <Exec Command="CALL mstest /TestContainer:$(Destination)\myApp\UnitTestmyApp\bin\Debug\UnitTestmyApp.dll /resultsfile:$(Destination)\testResults.trx /category:MyTest"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: After that you can call Ant and do rest of your work.